# How to redirect wordpress website based on city?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect my WordPress website to another if someone open in Singapore. I tried [ipinfodb](http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) to do this task without using plugin but sometime its giving error.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://ipinfo.io/33.44.66.77): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/web/public_html/web/demo/web/wp-content/themes/web-child/header-home.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible,

the reason for that is that a IP is not bound to the location the person is living. In Germany people have sometimes a polish, serbian or france IP address. A way better way of solving this issue is to use a tld.

- mysite.kr for korean
- mysite.jp for japan
- mysite.vn for vietnam

Some Translation plugins support this too, polylang or wpml for example.